# How do I put the output(dna complement of an array into another array to display the output

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to put the output from a complement method into an array so I can display the results. Here's some of my code:

```
public class BasicBioinformatics {


public static char[] complement(char dna) {
    for(char d: dna())
        if(d == 'A') {
            d = 'T';
        }
        else if(d == 'T') {
        d = 'A';
    }
        else if(d == 'G') {
        d = 'C';
    }
        else if(d == 'C') {
        d = 'G';
    
        }
        else {
            return null; }
    }
     
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testData1 = "GCCTGTCGTAGCTTATC", testData2 = "GGCTGACGTAGCGTAAC";
    System.out.printf("%s <-- complement --> %s%n", testData1, complement(testData1));
    
}
```

}

Comment: I'm able to display the results but only in printing each letter which shows the result but It's not in an array

Comment: You would need to create the new array. Just create one the same size as the original, and the go through the first array and put the complement of each element into the same index of the complement array.

Comment: Do you actually want a `char[]` or a `String`?

Comment: A char array, do i make a seperate char array or on the for method because it says for this line of code '   for(char d: dna) ' it can only be iterated over an array.

Answer (score 1):

You have `function complement(char dna)` but you try to input a `String`. You can instead use  `System.out.printf("%s <-- complement --> %s%n", testData1, (complement(testData1.toCharArray())));`